# Write .dat file to serial port to update firmware using C#

Tags: c#, gps, serial-port, embed

I am making application using C# to update firmware by writing a file to serial port. How can I send a binary .dat file to the serial port in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `SerialPort` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx

Here is some code that may help you:

```
string path = ""; // Your file path.

byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

// Initialize the port using a name, a baud rate value and a parity value.
using (var port = new SerialPort("COM1", 4800, Parity.None))     
{
    port.Open();

    port.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

of course this assumes you don't have to add any custom protocol header to the data you send, and that you don't have to check for any confirm response from the device.

Comment: It will not support.. I have Y Modem file write.. can you please help me on this.. I have upload firmware ( Y Modem )

Comment: give me your email id or skype I wanna show you issue what exactly going on when I send file to device.

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to implement the YModem protocol yourself or look for a 3rd party library.

Comment: I have not used any library on serial port writeline function use.. I am stuck over there.. not getting any solution for this.